# Scrapy Broad Crawl - implement errback's to catch exceptions

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I'm trying to implement errbacks to catch exceptions in request processing based on the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-errbacks-to-catch-exceptions-in-request-processing) but I can't get it to work. The difference between the documentation example and my code is that mine is a Broad Crawl. I also tried the stackoverflow answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35866873/scrapy-get-website-with-error-dns-lookup-failed) but I couldn't get it to work.
My end goal is to catch those exceptions and pass them into Items

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from crawler.items import DomainItem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

from scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror import HttpError
from twisted.internet.error import DNSLookupError
from twisted.internet.error import TimeoutError

denylist = [
    'google.com',
]

class Crawler (CrawlSpider):
    name = "crawler"
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[r'quotes.toscrape1.com'], deny=(denylist)), follow=True, 
            callback='parse_item', errback='error_back'),)

    start_urls = [
        "http://quotes.toscrape1.com/",
    ]


    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.logger.info('LOGGER %s', response.url)
        l = ItemLoader(item=DomainItem(), response=response)
        l.add_value('domain', response.url)
        return l.load_item()


    def error_back(self, failure):
        # log all failures
        self.logger.error(repr(failure))


        if failure.check(HttpError):
            # these exceptions come from HttpError spider middleware
            # you can get the non-200 response
            response = failure.value.response
            self.logger.error('HttpError on %s', response.url)

        elif failure.check(DNSLookupError):
            # this is the original request
            request = failure.request
            self.logger.error('DNSLookupError on %s', request.url)

        elif failure.check(TimeoutError, TCPTimedOutError):
            request = failure.request
            self.logger.error('TimeoutError on %s', request.url)
```

Comment: Your code if fine, but the errback will only be called for the URLs found by your CrawlSpider subclass, the `start_urls` are not configured with an errback. Consider using a regular Spider subclass, and using `start_requests` to define an errback for the start URLs.

Comment: The regular Spider subclass doesn't do a broad crawl though.

Comment: It does whatever you want it to do. Check the source code of `CrawlSpider` for inspiration, it’s rather short.